# .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.8669 - Failed to CoCreate profiler Error while running Dotnet Console Application

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application, profiler

I am trying to run a console application using the exe. The application crashes with the following error in Event viewer.

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: ncaaffeed.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 5965e2aa
P4: Oracle.DataAccess
P5: 2.112.1.0
P6: 4b8a191a
P7: 968
P8: 2bf
P9: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.Oracle
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\feeduser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_ncaaffeed.exe_651c088fc233586774617b648d6d690c01efd_00000000_522ced0c

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 944ff64b-66f8-11e7-80fd-0050569707c6
Report Status: 2048
Hashed bucket:
```

The dotnet framework is 3.5.
**This just works fine in the development machine. With exe and debug mode as well.**
I did check for similar errors online but nothing helped me get some clue on what is causing this issue.

I also tried using Process Monitor to troubleshoot, but i could not get to the root cause of this issue.

Any information on the error above will help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add `Try ... Catch...End Try` statements in  your code to catch and log exceptions to get more information.

Comment: Added a unhandled exception handler in the code. This was something related to tnsnames.ora file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Added a global exception handler in the code. This error was something related to tnsnames.ora file where the port number was wrong. Thanks.